# Creating table with rowspan php

Tags: php, html, html-table

I have been trying to figure out how to create the below table in php that i then include on another page, table i want to create is:

[image: What I want to display]

I have been using the below code which works on the first rowspan rows but not any others:

```
<?php
    $tbl1 = sqlsrv_query($connys,"

    select SectorTitle,DataTitle,sum(Aug18)[Aug18],sum(Sep18)[Sep18],sum(Oct18)[Oct18],sum(Nov18)[Nov18],sum(Dec18)[Dec18],sum(Jan19)[Jan19],sum(Feb19)[Feb19],sum(Mar19)[Mar19],sum(Apr19)[Apr19],sum(May19)[May19],sum(Jun19)[Jun19],sum(Jul19)[Jul19]
    from tblsomename

    ");
    if($tbl1 === false){
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($tbl1, SQLSRV_FETCH_BOTH)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td rowspan='3'>".$row['SectorTitle']++."</td>";

        while( $row2 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($tbl1, SQLSRV_FETCH_BOTH)){
    $DataTitle=$row2['DataTitle'];
    $Aug=$row2['Aug18'];
    $Sep=$row2['Sep18'];
    $Oct=$row2['Oct18'];
    $Nov=$row2['Nov18'];
    $Dec=$row2['Dec18'];
    $Jan=$row2['Jan19'];
    $Feb=$row2['Feb19'];
    $Mar=$row2['Mar19'];
    $Apr=$row2['Apr19'];
    $May=$row2['May19'];
    $Jun=$row2['Jun19'];
    $Jul=$row2['Jul19'];
    echo "<td>$DataTitle</td><td>$Aug</td><td>$Sep</td><td>$Oct</td><td>$Nov</td><td>$Dec</td><td>$Jan</td><td>$Feb</td><td>$Mar</td><td>$Apr</td><td>$May</td><td>$Jun</td><td>$Jul</td></tr>";
    }

    }

    ?>
```

The query is not the actual query but gives you an idea as it does pull through the same headers. This is then included into another php file that inserts it between the  tags etc.

What my code currently produces is:

[image]

Which is correct although i can't seem to get it to loop through the sectortitle bit

Comment: You should debug `$row` and `$row2`, I think your loop aren't that good :/

Comment: Looks like you need to add a `</tr>` after the inside `while` has ended (between the 2 closing braces).

Comment: Isn't there some condition on the `while` missing? The first while will be processed only once, and all the other data will be processed in the second `while` - cause you loop on the same result set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can contend with a single while loop with some added logic to handle the spanned row:

```
$SectorTitle = "";

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($tbl1, SQLSRV_FETCH_BOTH)){
    echo "<tr>";

    // Check if there is a new sectortitle
    if($SectorTitle != $row['SectorTitle']) {
        $SectorTitle = $row['SectorTitle'];
        echo "<td rowspan='3'>$SectorTitle</td>";
    }

    $DataTitle=$row['DataTitle'];
    $Aug=$row['Aug18'];
    $Sep=$row['Sep18'];
    $Oct=$row['Oct18'];
    $Nov=$row['Nov18'];
    $Dec=$row['Dec18'];
    $Jan=$row['Jan19'];
    $Feb=$row['Feb19'];
    $Mar=$row['Mar19'];
    $Apr=$row['Apr19'];
    $May=$row['May19'];
    $Jun=$row['Jun19'];
    $Jul=$row['Jul19'];
    echo "<td>$DataTitle</td><td>$Aug</td><td>$Sep</td><td>$Oct</td><td>$Nov</td><td>$Dec</td><td>$Jan</td><td>$Feb</td><td>$Mar</td><td>$Apr</td><td>$May</td><td>$Jun</td><td>$Jul</td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: Happy to hear it! Is this a report that you will need to output regularly? I'm asking because I think there's a fairly simple way to avoid the hardcoded month names and make it a bit more dynamic, but if it's just going to be used once then there's not point.